# Laravel Eloquent GroupBy throwing SQL error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

When I run the below SQL manually I get my expected results with no error

```sql
select * from `crawl_results` 
    where `user_id` = 1 and `website_id` = 1 
    and `item_state` != 'OK' group by `destination_url` 
    limit 30 offset 0
```

However when I run this in Eloquent...

```php
self::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('website_id', $scanID)
    ->where('item_state', '!=' , 'OK')
    ->groupby('destination_url')->paginate(30)
```

It produces this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'link_checker.crawl_results.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from
>   `crawl_results` where `user_id` = 1 and `website_id` = 1 and
>   `item_state` != OK group by `destination_url` limit 30 offset 0)

Not sure what is happening behind the abstraction to produce that error?

Comment: Can you log the raw query that is getting generated form your eloquent query?

Comment: I believe the raw query is in the error it throws?

Comment: Can you run the query directly into your phpmyadmin and then if you are getting error adding table prefix to group by column name and tell me the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to a query builder query

```
DB::table('crawl_results')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('website_id', $scanID)->where('item_state', '!=' , 'OK')->groupby('destination_url')->paginate(30);
```

It should work fine.

In [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) it is mentioned that GROUP BY can not be executed efficiently in pagination

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

Answer (score 4):

You should go to  **config\database.php** and change **strict** to **false**

```
'mysql' => [
   ...
   'strict' => false,
   ...
 ]
```

Comment: That will cause other security issues.